# Python: How do I open the most recent file in my downloads directory?

Tags: python, csv, selenium-webdriver, download, operating-system

I have a button in my UI that I am clicking which downloads a .csv file:

```
def download_log_events(self):
    self.event_record_dropdown()
    download_bttn = self.driver.find_element(*Elements.download_as_csv)
    download_bttn.click()
```

The .csv file is saved as the most recent file in my downloads folder, and I need some advice on how to open this file using Python. Currently I have the following:

```
import os

def open_downloaded_file(self):
dir_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Downloads\\")
```

If you can provide any help on what I should do next or how to open a file downloaded to my local machine, it would be great!

Comment: Try `dir_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), max(os.listdir("Downloads\\"), key=os.path.getctime))`

Comment: I'm getting the error 'The system cannot find the path specificed 'Downloads\\'

Comment: Try `os.chdir('Downloads\\')` first and then `dir_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), max(os.listdir("."), key=os.path.getctime))`

Comment: I'm still getting the same error :(

os.chdir('Downloads\\')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'Downloads\\'

Comment: I think you should pass absolute path. If you use Windows it should be something like `os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Golshy\\Downloads")`

Comment: I managed to locate the most recently downloaded csv by using glob: 

import glob
    def open_downloaded_file(self, directory):
        newest_csv = max(glob.iglob(os.path.join(directory, '*.csv')), key=os.path.getctime)
        return newest_csv